# How do we show that it is a subset of the centralizer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H, M \leq G$.

I want to show that if $H,M\trianglelefteq G$ and $H\cap M=1$ then $H\subseteq C_G(M)$.

$$$$

We have that $$C_G(M)=\{g\in G\mid gm=mg, \forall m\in M\}$$

$$$$

I have done the following:

Let $h\in H$.

Since $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ we have that $ghg^{-1}\in H, \forall g\in G$ ans since $M$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ we have that $gmg^{-1}\in M, \forall g\in G$.

What does it mena that $H\cap M=1$ ? That the only common element of the subgroups $H$ and $M$ is the identity element?

How do we use this information?

Answer (score 1):

Given $h\in H$, you need to prove that $h\in C_G(M)=\{g\in G\mid gm=mg, \forall m\in M\}$, that is, $hm=mh,\ \forall m\in M$.  This is equivalent to showing that $$hmh^{-1}m^{-1}=1,\ \forall m\in M.$$

Here are some observations you can make based on the given information.

1) $hmh^{-1}\in M$, since $M$ is normal (you've done that). So, $hmh^{-1}m^{-1}=(hmh^{-1})m^{-1}$ is in $M$.

2) $mh^{-1}m^{-1}\in H$, since $H$ is normal (you've done that).  So, $hmh^{-1}m^{-1}=h(mh^{-1}m^{-1})$ is in $H$.

Therefore, $hmh^{-1}m^{-1}$ is in $H\cap M$.

Answer (score 0):

Note $H\subseteq C_G(M)$ iff $[H,M]=1$, that is to say, $[h,m]=hmh^{-1}m^{-1}=1$ for all $h\in H$ and $m\in M$. But $[h,m]\in H\cap M$, since both are normal subgroups.